# Embedding HTML code in beamer

Tags: beamer, html

I want to embed html code like latex in beamer, like follows:

```
  \begin{frame}{HTML Code}[fragile]
   \begin{lstlisting}[language=html]
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
  \end{lstlisting}
   \end{frame}
```

But it is not working , Latex file is giving compilation errors. It is really urgent. Please help.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Remarks

The order of your parameters for the frame is wrong. The options in `[]` need to appear before the title in `{}`.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{HTML Code}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=html]
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image: frame]

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, consider marking it as accepted answer. If you don't know how, take a look here: [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)